# Name expressions in Boost Spirit without assignment to a rule

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

Is it possible to name an expression in Boost Spirit without its assignment to a rule?

I know you can name it by assignment to a rule like:

```
using boost::spirit::standard::char_;
boost::spirit::qi::rule<> number = char_("0") | (char_("1-9") >> *char_("0-9"));
number.name("number");
```

Which makes debugging of syntax errors easier as you can already have the particular part named in the right way.

But is it possible to do this inline in such a way?

```
using boost::spirit::standard::char_;
boost::spirit::qi::rule<> twoDigits = char_("0-9") > name(char_("0-9"), "digit");
```

So that the exception would say that it expected a "digit" at position 2 if it got an input like "3a" (it is not really important here that it is position 2).

The alternative way to express this would be:

```
using boost::spirit::standard::char_;
boost::spirit::qi::rule<> digit = char_("0-9");
digit.name("digit");
boost::spirit::qi::rule<> twoDigits = digit > digit;
```

I already checked the source and found out that the expression have a function called what(), which returns a boost::spirit::info object from which the string representation can be retrieved. But I was not able to overwrite that as I am not familier with Boost Proto and the internals of Boost Spirit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using a custom directive. You can see a very good explanation of how to do something similar (it's a parser, not a directive) [here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/creating-your-own-parser-component-for-spirit-qi/).

The process of creating a custom parser/directive can be divided in four parts:

1. **Defining/creating a terminal to use in a Spirit expression.** Usually you'll use `BOOST_SPIRIT_TERMINAL` unless you need your parser/directive to be of the form `parser(whatever)`/`directive(whatever)[subject]`. In this case you'll need to use `BOOST_SPIRIT_TERMINAL_EX`. This case is specially strange in that you need state associated with your terminal, and so you need to define a struct deriving from `terminal<tag::stateful_tag,...>`. This is usually not required. I've decided to put all this in namespace `custom_directive` but you could also put it inside `boost::spirit::qi`.
2. **Enabling your parser/directive.** Here you need to specialize either `use_terminal`(for parsers) or `use_directive`(for directives) inside namespace `boost::spirit`.
3. **Creating the actual parser/directive.** This parser/directive requires three things: a `attribute<Context,Iterator>::type` associated metafunction that states what the attribute of your parser is(in this case I have simply passed the attribute of the subject parser through); a `parse` member function with the appropiate signature that does the real parsing (again I have deferred to the subject parser), and a `what` member function that is what we really are interested in modifying that returns whatever you have associated with the terminal on construction. Again I have decided to use namespace `custom_directive` but you could also put it inside `boost::spirit::qi`.
4. **Connecting the terminal with your actual parser/directive.** This needs to be inside `boost::spirit::qi` and requires that you specialize either `make_directive` or `make_primitive` with your terminal tag and instatiate your actual parser/directive.

[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbabf6b0afb69ef7)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>


//START OF expression_renamer.hpp

namespace custom_directive
{
    BOOST_SPIRIT_TERMINAL(rename_expression);

    struct expression_renamer: boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::stateful_tag<std::string, tag::rename_expression> >
    {
        typedef boost::spirit::tag::stateful_tag<std::string, tag::rename_expression> tag_type;

        expression_renamer(std::string const& p) : boost::spirit::terminal<tag_type>(p) {}
    };
}

namespace boost { namespace spirit
{
    template <>
    struct use_directive<qi::domain, boost::spirit::tag::stateful_tag<std::string, custom_directive::tag::rename_expression> >   // enables expression_renamer[p]
      : mpl::true_ {};
}}

namespace custom_directive
{
    template <typename Subject, typename Data>
    struct rename_directive : boost::spirit::qi::unary_parser<rename_directive<Subject,Data> >
    {
        typedef Subject subject_type;
        rename_directive(Subject const& subject_, Data const& data_)
          : subject(subject_),data(data_) {}

        template <typename Context, typename Iterator>
        struct attribute
        {
            typedef typename
                boost::spirit::traits::attribute_of<subject_type, Context, Iterator>::type
            type;
        };

        template <typename Iterator, typename Context
          , typename Skipper, typename Attribute>
        bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last, Context& context, Skipper const& skipper, Attribute& attr_) const
        {
            return subject.parse(first, last, context, skipper, attr_);
        }


        template <typename Context>
        boost::spirit::info what(Context& context) const
        {
            return boost::spirit::info(data);

        }

        Subject subject;
        Data data;
    };
}


// instantiation of the parser
namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace qi 
{
      template<typename Data, typename Subject,typename Modifiers>
      struct make_directive<tag::stateful_tag<Data, custom_directive::tag::rename_expression>, Subject, Modifiers>
      {
        typedef custom_directive::rename_directive<Subject,Data> result_type;

        template<typename Terminal>
        result_type operator()(Terminal& term, Subject const& subject, unused_type) const 
        {
          typedef tag::stateful_tag<Data,
              custom_directive::tag::rename_expression> tag_type;
          using spirit::detail::get_stateful_data;
          return result_type(subject,get_stateful_data<tag_type>::call(term));
        }
      };
}}}


//END OF expression_renamer.hpp

template <typename Parser>
void parse(std::string const& str, Parser const& parser)
{
    std::cout << "Parsing: \"" << str << "\"" << " with `digit` `point` `digit`" << std::endl;
    std::string::const_iterator iter=str.begin(),end=str.end();

    boost::spirit::qi::parse(iter,end,parser);
}

int main()
{
    custom_directive::expression_renamer point("point");
    custom_directive::expression_renamer digit("digit");
    boost::spirit::qi::char_type char_;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator> twoDigitsWithPoint = char_("0-9") > point[char_('.')] > digit[char_("0-9")];
    boost::spirit::qi::on_error<boost::spirit::qi::fail>
        (
            twoDigitsWithPoint
          , std::cout
                << boost::phoenix::val("Error! Expecting ")
                << boost::spirit::qi::_4                               // what failed?
                << std::endl
        );
    parse("33",twoDigitsWithPoint);
    parse("3.a",twoDigitsWithPoint);

}
```

Comment: Very nice example and explaination. This almost gave me the syntax I wanted. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f9a72bcbb6702ac with little adjustments to your code close to the syntax in the example of my question.

Comment: +1 Craziness. I wonder what exactly this buys the OP (e.g. is it actually more lightweight now? Or just less typing - leading to longer rule definitions)

Comment: Not sure if this is more lightweight now but it enables you to name parts of an expression without the need to define a rule for that. On Windows I got a 1KiB bigger executable with that than using rules when I compile it with GCC 5.2.0 in 32-bit mode. This solution turns out in a 1KiB smaller executable when I compile it in 64-bit mode with the same compiler and build options.

Answer (score 0):

You can group using `auto`. But debug names can only be attached to the non-terminals: `qi::rule<>` and `qi::grammar<>` (other "groupings" aren't traced anyways, not even with `attr_cast<>`, which is semantically close to the attribute propagation semantics of a `rule<>`).

---

There is a big caveat related to using `auto`:

Proto expression trees need to be deep copied. Recent Qi defines `qi::copy()` to do just that.

Comment: It is not really about the tracing. It is more about the expection handling where an exception is thrown at the position where a specific expression was expected. The exception thrown contains in what() an info element which represents the whole expression which was expected. This was you can tell the user about syntax errors in detail and you can also abort syntax parsing in a very early stage. I thought is would be possible to overwrite that info value by some kind of directive. That does not necessarily means that I do not need to write my own directive for that but I was not able to do so.

Comment: @user2525536 I've tried to write a custom directive that I think does what you want.